# How to access function's state from last bar

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Modifying global state in PineScript is prohibited. Like so:

```
globalVar = 0

function() =>
    globalVar := 1
```

So how do i access a value which was calcualted the last iteration (the last bar) within i function if you can not persist it in global scope?

In other languages an option would be to return the values from the function and feed them to the function call in the next bar, like so:

```
increment(i, modified) =>
    modified2 = nz(modified, i) + 1
    [i, modified2]
state = increment(0, array.get(state[1], 1))
```

However, this fails because `state` is not valid. Which makes sense since it can not be read before it was defined. But on the other hand in the last bar `state[1]` it was defined.

So how would I access the `modified` variable from the function's scope from the last bar to increment it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is correct that you cannot modify global scope variables from inside functions, you can modify elements of a globally declared array from inside a function.

Because the array is declared using `var` it is persistent, so it does not re-initialize on each bar. The successive increments are thus preserved not only on the same bar (we increment three times on each bar here), but across bars also:

```
//@version=5
indicator("")
// Create an array of one element of value zero.
var globalArray = array.from(0)
// Increase the array's element by 1 from inside the function.
increment(a) =>
    newValue = array.get(a, 0) + 1
    array.set(a, 0, newValue)
    newValue

plot(increment(globalArray))
plot(increment(globalArray))
plot(increment(globalArray))
```

Answer (score -1):

there is no array in pine script. they work in the form of series.

for simply calling the last close:
last_close = close[1]
2nd_last_close = close[2]

Comment: Pine Script™ **does** support arrays. See [here in the usrman](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Arrays.html), and in the code in our answer.